# Calculating sample size for a composite endpoint

Tags: sample-size

I am trying to figure out how to calculate sample size for a composite endpoint.

Say I have two groups, group A and B, and I want to know how they do after taking two different medications (let's forget the control for now). And if from a preliminary study, I observed that upon taking the medications, group A on average has blood sugar of 130 with a certain standard deviation and group B average of 110 with a certain standard deviation, I can just use a program to determine the sample size I need for a given alpha and power. How should I approach this if I have more than one measure to look at (say I want to take blood sugar, weight change, and blood pressure into account when I calculate the necessary sample size).